# How can I load values into an HTML form with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, load

I'm trying to create an ajax form with jQuery. I'd like to load existing values into the different form fields (text boxes, dropdown menus). Would I use JSON for this? And how would I load the values? Iterate through the JSON and for each entry load the corresponding value? How would this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could either use JSON, XML, or even your own approach to tranfer data from the server. When do you want get the data? When the users clicks on some button, when the selects something in a list box, etc???

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that your are not loading them in from your server side code?

The overhead of converting into JSON and then loading into the form using JavaScript/jQuery would be much greater that simply populating them with server-side script code. Not to mention adding the requirement that any browser must have Javascript turned on to view your page.

Comment: It's going to be used for an intranet application, I am trying to avoid refreshing the page

Comment: @Jo you can still load the entire form with ajax and server side code without refreshing the page.